# Custom property on individual QTabBar item for stylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qtabwidget

I have a `QTabWidget` and I want a property on the individual tabs that holds whether the tab is persistent or not (similar to the tabs in VSCode, where if you don't double click a file it won't persist in the editor)

I have this so far. I want the `TabItem`'s with `_persistent=False` to be in italic's and the others to be in normal font.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class TabItem(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, persistent=False):
        super(TabItem, self).__init__()
        self._persistent = persistent
        self.setProperty('persistent', '0' if not persistent else '1')


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__()

        item1 = TabItem(persistent=False)
        item2 = TabItem(persistent=True)

        self.addTab(item1, 'FirstItem')
        self.addTab(item2, 'SecondItem')

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QTabBar::tab{
                font: normal;
            }
            QTabBar::tab[persistent="0"]{
                font: italic;
            }
        """)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TabWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style sheet pseudo selectors don't support property selectors, because properties are set for the *widget*, whereas pseudo selectors are *elements* of that widget.

The only way to achieve that (besides completely overriding the `paintEvent()` of the QTabBar) is through a [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html), and by implementing `drawControl`.

The trick is to find which tab the current option rect belongs to, and eventually check the property of that tab to set the font.

```
class TabStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, ctl, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if ctl == self.CE_TabBarTabLabel:
            for i in range(widget.count()):
                tabRect = widget.tabRect(i)
                if tabRect == opt.rect:
                    tabWidget = widget.parent()
                    try:
                        if tabWidget.widget(i)._persistent:
                            qp.save()
                            font = qp.font()
                            font.setItalic(True)
                            qp.setFont(font)
                            super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)
                            qp.restore()
                            return
                    except:
                        pass
        super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)

# ...
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(TabStyle())
```